# Why my json is returning false?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I need some help, i can't understand why my json is returning false...
This is my Ajax :

```
var xhr10 = getXhr();
length=document.getElementById('ChoosenStuff').options.length;
ListChoosenStuffNames = [];
for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    ListChoosenStuffNames[i] = document.getElementById('ChoosenStuff').options[i].value;
}

xhr10.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr10.readyState === 4 && xhr10.status === 200){
        Selection = JSON.parse(xhr10.responseText); 
        for(var i = 0; i < Selection.length; i++) { 
            document.getElementById('ShowResult').innerHTML += Selection[i] + "\n\r";
        }
    }
};
xhr10.open("POST","Ajax/AjaxGetDTravauxCorrespondant.php",true);
xhr10.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr10.send("ListChoosenStuffNames="+ListChoosenStuffNames);
```

And then my php file with my query which works on phpMyAdmin :

```
include '../Reglage/ConnexionBDD.php';
$res = [];

    $Query="Select NomDomaineTravaux from equipement 
    JOIN typeequipement ON equipement.CodeTypeEquipement = 
    typeequipement.CodeTypeEquipement 
    JOIN domainetravaux ON typeequipement.IDDomaineTravaux = 
    domainetravaux.IDDomaineTravaux
    WHERE NomEquipement=:stuff";
    $rep = $bdd->prepare($Query);
    $custom = $_POST['nomsEquipementsChoisis'];
    $rep->bindParam(':stuff',$custom);
    $rep->execute();
    $NomDomaineTravaux= $rep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $res[$i]= $NomDomaineTravaux;
echo json_encode($res, true);
```

I have {NomDomaineTravaux: "Divers"}
how do i use this to display "Divers" in my js file with obj = JSON.parse(xhr.reponseText) ?

I tried obj.NomDomaineTravaux but it says that he dont recognize this... :(

Thanks A LOT,

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Anyway what do you mean "returning false"? It seems it will always return an array, either empty or populated. I don't see how it's possible it could return "false".

Comment: What happens if you amend this line so it does not have a line break in it `WHERE NomEquipement='".$_POST['nomsEquipementsChoisis'][$i]."'";`

Comment: I know it for sql injection, i will add the good function to make it safe after.

Comment: Do that NOW and you problem will probably dissappear

Comment: `The only I getted was a list of numbers`...ok so what is contained in the field "NomDomaineTravaux" exactly? That's the only field you select from the database. Therefore that's the only data which will be returned from the server 
in your JSON. We cannot see your data, so we don't know if that's the issue, or something else. P.S. Why wait to fix your SQL injection? It just means you have to re-test everything later. Fix it now and save yourself time and trouble. And in future write your queries correctly by default.

Comment: There is not new line in my query, the code was formatted by the paste in the StackOverFlow textbox

Comment: `json_encode($res, true);` ... `true` is not a correct options constant. (it wont fix your problem, I'm just saying).

Comment: to add to @IncredibleHat 's point, http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php and http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php documents what you _can_ pass in for the second argument (which is optional).

Comment: I corrected with prepared query.

Comment: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr10.onreadystatechange

Comment: hm, this indicates that your JSON is invalid (unlikely, assuming json_encode() succeeded (which of course it might not, you can check that by seeing whether it ever returns `false` - so actually that contradicts my first ever comment, sorry)), or that you also echoed some content which is not JSON. Use your browser's network tools to view the ajax request and check the entire response the server gives. Look out for invisible problems such as extra whitespace or special characters.

Comment: Yup, do as @ADyson mentions to look at the raw response in the network tab... sounds like php is tossing some html errors/warnings in front of the json.

Comment: $rep->bindParam(':stuff',$_POST['nomsEquipementsChoisis'][$i]);

Comment: Only variables can be passed by reference at this line :s

Comment: The ole 'references' headache with those stupid bind functions.... Change `bindParam` to `bindValue` and try.

Comment: And my query returning an only word 'Divers' when i'm testing it

Comment: "my query returning an only word 'Divers' " well presumably this is because only one row was matched, and of course you only return a single column. What did you expect to happen? You didn't make clear. Again, _we can't see your data_.

Comment: Is it possible to have a $_POST variable wich is an array ?

Comment: Ok so i i want to do this trick no matter if there is a single or multiple string in my $_POST

Comment: "Is it possible to have a $_POST variable wich is an array"...yes, if that's what you send to the server. But you can't just pass a whole array direct to a "WHERE" clause in SQL, you'd have to split it out and use an IN clause or something I guess.

Comment: Ok so i do : $custom = $_POST[][$i]; and then use custom to bindParam and i get my false return from php file

Comment: You so in that case you need to amend the question to show us what you're actually doing. The code above does not include what you've just mentioned. Also show us a sample of the actual data which is in the $_POST, a sample of the data in the database and what your expected result is. Because the more you comment, the less clear it is becoming. Also have you checked _why_ your JSON is false yet? See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: OK so in my php file the form data are : ListChoosenStuffNames: Test     Thats what i want to use for my query

Comment: That's not really what I asked for....anyway please edit the question comprehensively to provide all the requested info, if you still can't figure it out. We can't carry on just guessing or making suggestions, we need hard data.

Comment: Ok my problem was about the number of item in $_POST if there is only one I have to do a different process.

Comment: {DomaineTravaux: {NomDomaineTravaux: "Divers"}} how i have to use result = JSON.parse(xhr.reponseText); to display the word "Divers" from my json ? i can't get the right syntax.

Comment: " the number of item in $_POST if there is only one I have to do a different process." you can check the size using something like `$size = sizeof($yourArrayVariable)`

Comment: `to display the word "Divers" from my json ?`... I should think `var name 
= result.DomaineTravaux.NomDomaineTravaux;`. You have an object, which has a property within it called `DomaineTravaux`. That property itself is an object, and it has another property `NomDomainTravaux` which contains the string "Divers". If you don't understand basic JSON syntax I suggest to study it using a tutorial or other online examples.

Comment: I tried to do result.DomaineTravaux.NomDomaineTravaux but they said unresolved variable for those two object...

Comment: "unresolved variable" is not an error message I'm familiar with. Does it come from the JS engine in the browser, or is it just a warning from some IDE you're using? What _exactly_ was the error, and on what line did it occur? Please be specific and accurate in your statements. Here is a demo showing that my suggestion should work: http://jsfiddle.net/pr7a2v4f/3/ (I had to change your JSON string to have double-quotes round the property names, otherwise they're not valid...but I suspect this is just a typo in your comment, since json_encode() would always do this correctly for you)